# Testing angular js directive with jsdom: $scope.digest() not invoking

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jsdom

We are testing angular js with jsdom and angular mocks.  I have a setup file that requires jsdom, angular, and angular mocks in that order.  Simple enough to set up tests with controllers and services.  I am running into issues with templateUrl.  I know with Karma you would have to set up a config.  I came across a github gist  where these tools were used together https://gist.github.com/rikukissa/dcb422eb3b464cc184ae  .

I am wondering how you would access the templateUrl?

Since jsdom runs with node so I required file systems and called readFileSync
    var fs = require('fs');
    template = $sce.trustAsHtml(fs.readFileSync('pathToTemplates, 'utf8'));

**Note $sce was required to allow me read the file.  I know the code is using version 1.5 and it should come instantiated, but I couple not compile without it.

Here is my current test using jasmine and jsdom

```
describe('hero Directive', function () {
  var $compile,
    $rootScope,
    scope,
    element,
    template,
    haConfig,
    $sce
    ctrl;

beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.module('ha.module.core');

    angular.mock.inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$controller_, $httpBackend, $templateCache) {
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        haConfig = _haConfig_;

        $templateCache.put("haConfig.getTemplateUrl('explore-hero-base-template.html')", template);
        var html = angular.element("<div explore-hero></div>");
        element = $compile(html)($scope)
```

html returns a value of

```
      {'0': HTMLDIVElement {239:2}, length: 1}
```

I understand the length property but the  **239:2 is confusing me a little bit.**

Last the issue that is stoping me from further debugging and fixing this test is that  $scope.digest() is not being called

```
   beforeEach(function()
```

stops after

```
 element = $compile(html)($scope)
```

ignores the digest and goes straight to the spec.

```
        $scope.$digest();
        console.log('called not being reached');
    });

});

afterEach(function () {
    // need to remove the element element.remove();
});

describe('directive controller', function () {
    it('should dispatch call $emit with $methodsBound', function () {
        spyOn(scope, '$emit');

        //expect(scope.$emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('$methodsBound');
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Not at all clear what you are trying to do...or where

Comment: Trying to configure jsdom to unit test angular directives that use templateUrl.

Comment: Why would you need to read template file in the first place and not read the angular generated dom itself? Again..not at all clear what you are trying to do

Comment: Not sure how to read the angular generated dom without configuring karma and  karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor.   I would ideally just use $templateCache.   I will show my current tests in jasmine to be clearer.

Comment: What would you expect to gain by reading what is in templateCache? That is uncompiled

Comment: If you see a fix to my logic which I know has faults (reason I am on here) please feel free to share it.  It would be greatly appreaciated.